systemd initrd fail with cryptsetup device timeout
I'm trying to run systemd inside my initramfs image. I have luks full disk ecnryption, and everything worked fine until I tried using my initramfs with raspberry pi. For some reason it decrypts device with the resulting name /dev/mapper/crypt0, reached Basic target, and then stuck waiting for the same device that was already created for endless loop.
record in /etc/crypttab:
crypt0   /dev/mmcblk0p2  /etc/luksKey   luks,nofail

What interesting in my opinion:
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot systemd[1]: Finished Cryptography Setup for crypt0.
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1338 audit(1716846520.311:4): module=crypt op=ctr ppid=1 pid=203 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) s1
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1300 audit(1716846520.311:4): arch=c00000b7 syscall=29 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=c138fd09 a2=55ae3e0e10 a3=55ae3d1010 items=6 ppid=1 pid=203 auid=42)
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1307 audit(1716846520.311:4): cwd="/"
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1302 audit(1716846520.311:4): item=0 name=(null) inode=1029 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=00
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1302 audit(1716846520.311:4): item=1 name=(null) inode=15326 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1302 audit(1716846520.311:4): item=2 name=(null) inode=19 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 c0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1302 audit(1716846520.311:4): item=3 name=(null) inode=15327 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot kernel: audit: type=1302 audit(1716846520.311:4): item=4 name=(null) inode=15327 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit[203]: SYSCALL arch=c00000b7 syscall=29 success=yes exit=0 a0=4 a1=c138fd09 a2=55ae3e0e10 a3=55ae3d1010 items=6 ppid=1 pid=203 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 su)
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: CWD cwd="/"
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: PATH item=0 name=(null) inode=1029 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: PATH item=1 name=(null) inode=15326 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: PATH item=2 name=(null) inode=19 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: PATH item=3 name=(null) inode=15327 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: PATH item=4 name=(null) inode=15327 dev=00:07 mode=040755 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=PARENT cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: PATH item=5 name=(null) inode=15328 dev=00:07 mode=0100444 ouid=0 ogid=0 rdev=00:00 nametype=CREATE cap_fp=0 cap_fi=0 cap_fe=0 cap_fver=0 cap_frootid=0
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot audit: PROCTITLE proctitle=2F7573722F6C69622F73797374656D642F73797374656D642D637279707473657475700061747461636800637279707430002F6465762F6D6D63626C6B307032002F6574632F6CC
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot (udev-worker)[175]: dm-0: Failed to create/update device symlink '/dev/mapper/crypt0', ignoring: File exists
May 27 21:48:40 buildroot systemd[1]: Reached target Block Device Preparation for /dev/mapper/crypt0.
May 27 21:49:05 buildroot systemd[1]: dev-mapper-crypt0.device: Job dev-mapper-crypt0.device/start timed out.
May 27 21:49:05 buildroot systemd[1]: Timed out waiting for device /dev/mapper/crypt0.
May 27 21:49:05 buildroot systemd[1]: Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/mapper/crypt0.
May 27 21:49:05 buildroot systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /sysroot.
May 27 21:49:05 buildroot systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Initrd Root File System.
May 27 21:49:05 buildroot systemd[1]: Dependency failed for Mountpoints Configured in the Real Root.

In fact device file exists:
~ # ls -la /dev/mapper/crypt0
brw-------    1 root     root      254,   0 May 27 21:48 /dev/mapper/crypt0

Complete boot log:
https://gist.github.com/onorua/81175409057d52c3d739fd3d918a021d
Any help how to identify the problem would be highly appreciated!
